# "git describe --tags" produces different output from same commit

Tags: git

We use `git describe --tags` to find the latest tag to build a version string.

On our CI host `git describe --tags` is reporting a different version than anywhere else I run it.

Here is a series of commands demonstrating the issue. I would expect the first one to report v3.9.0 as the others do.

```
$ git checkout 190670
HEAD is now at 1906709 Merge pull request #1978 from <redacted>

$ git describe --tags
v3.7.0-391-g1906709

$ git log --oneline --decorate=short | grep "v3."
c7c04e0 (tag: v3.9.0) Merge pull request #1927 from <redacted>
e88c30c (tag: v3.8.0) Merge pull request #1899 from <redacted>
4488ab1 (tag: v3.7.0) Merge pull request #1784 from <redacted>

$ git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --sort=-authordate --count=1 refs/tags
v3.9.0
```

On a different machine with the same version of git, it works as expected. I think the only difference is that the CI machine does some kind of shallow clone of the repository.

Comment: How many commits are between `v3.7.0-391` and `HEAD`? How many commits are between `v3.9.0` and `HEAD`? Is this different on the different devices/machines/systems?

Comment: Are your tags annotated or lightweight? This discussion might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089002/git-describe-with-two-tags-on-the-same-commit

Comment: A shallow clone *could* affect the output: by default, a tag itself is copied if and only if the commit it tags is copied. Consider modifying your CI system to run `git fetch --tags` or to use a full (non-shallow) clone.

Comment: @jingx tags are lightweight.

Comment: @dan1st I believe there are 391 commits between v3.7.0 and HEAD... that's what the -391 means the tag itself is just "v3.7.0" for v3.9.0 there are fewer... I can see this if I just page through the output of `git log`, v3.9.0 comes up first, then v3.8.0, then v3.7.0.

Comment: @torek the weird thing is that the tags are *there* as you can see from the commands I ran, but something in the way git calculates the output for `describe` is different between our CI host and other places we have the repo.

Comment: @matt see the link I posted. there is some discussion on git's behavior with lightweight tags.