# Select Git tag from a "list"

Tags: git

We are using tags in our build, so it is possible to see which tag a specific SW stems from. Furthermore we add some information in the tag like revision and date to help technicians in the field.

Since we have several products build on a shared platform, it happens that several tags are put on the same commit.

If I have e.g. 3 tags on the same commit and I checkout a specific tag (git checkout <tag_1>) both git (git bash) and (git) describe will only show the last entered tag (tag 3) which is then injected to the release. This means that product 1 will get a tag for product 3, even though I checkout on the tag for product 1?

Is it possible to checkout a specific tag on the commit so that is the one shown?

Comment: When you say "node" do you mean commit?

Comment: Yes: A specific commit on the master branch, which is tagged.

Comment: You don't check out a tag, you check out a commit. The tag is only used to figure out which commit to check out, but after you've checked out that commit the information about which tag you actually checked out seems to be buried in the comment of the reflog entry, "HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from main to b" (`b` was the tag I checked out). Instead of just checking out the commit and then let other code figure out what you checked out, can't you just pass the tag name to that other code?

Comment: Similar to what @LasseV.Karlsen proposed, when you "inject" the tag into the release, perhaps you could simply filter the tag by name which corresponds to the product you are creating.

Answer (score 2):

As [Lasse V. Karlsen noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085518/select-git-tag-from-a-list#comment127368970_72085518), Git doesn't save the identity of the *tag name* used to select some particular commit, just the *hash ID* of that commit.  So in general, if you have more than one tag that names one commit, there's no unique reverse mapping from hash ID to tag and Git can't tell you how you got here.

The `HEAD` reflog *does* contain the necessary information as a sort of a comment, but reflogs are not entirely reliable.  In particular, they can be turned off, or the entries can expire.  There is also no promise that this will be true in the future, or that the format will remain the same.

If you have control of the build process, you can simply save the tag name you use (or it uses) to *do* the `git checkout` or `git clone` or `git switch` or whatever step.  Then, instead of running `git describe` or similar to find the tag, just use the saved name.  In short, if you supplied it, you can remember it.

Of course, sometimes things are not this simple: you did supply it, but to commercial (or free) software X, and the build server is commercial (or free) software Y, and X and Y refuse to talk to each other, so that you cannot deliver the tag name *from* X *to* Y.  Furthermore software Y *insists* on using `git describe` (only).  In this case you have several remaining remedies:

1. Delete, from the repository on which you're doing the build, the irrelevant tags that `git describe` *might* use.  Since we often use temporary clones for the build process, then destroy the temporary clone, this might be easy to do and damage nothing.
2. Make sure you never re-use a tag for one commit.

The latter is easy enough to do.  It just requires a bit of care and one trick.  A Git commit represents a state: an author, a committer, a timestamp, a log message, and other metadata, plus a snapshot.

A *tag name* holds a Git object ID: that of a *tag object* (an annotated tag), or that of a commit.  When the name holds the ID of a tag object, the tag object holds, or otherwise resolves to, a commit hash ID, and it's this commit that `git checkout` or `git switch --detach` ends up using:

```
git checkout v1.2
```

resolves the name `v1.2` to an object ID, and if that's a tag object, follows the tag objects until it arrives at a commit object.  Whatever hash ID it gets at that point is the commit that becomes your detached HEAD.

We need that commit hash ID to *uniquely* map back to *one* tag name or object.  That can only happen if there's only one such tag.  So if we need to tag the *same snapshot again*, we have to duplicate the snapshot.

But that's easy!  If we have some commit, say `96800d2` for short, and we need to make a duplicate of it to tag again, we just check it out by hash ID or tag name, then run `git commit` to make a new commit for our new tag.  There's just one hitch, illustrated here along with the way around it:

```
$ git checkout t1
[snippage]
HEAD is now at 96800d2 Initial commit
$ git commit -m "duplicate t1 for t2"
HEAD detached at t1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git tag
t1
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "duplicate t1 for t2"
[detached HEAD 4e69364] duplicate t1 for t2
$ git tag -m "new tag t2 for release purposes, same as t1" t2
$ git tag
t1
t2
```

Our new tag `t2` exists now and tags commit `4e69364`, not `96800d2`.  The two commits contain identical snapshots but different metadata, and `git log` shows us why we have the extra commit:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 4e69364 (HEAD, tag: t2) duplicate t1 for t2
* 96800d2 (tag: t1, main, branch-y, branch-x) Initial commit
```

As desired, `git describe` now describes this as `t2`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another question someone else referred me to.
[git describe with two tags on the same commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089002/git-describe-with-two-tags-on-the-same-commit)

This method fixed my problem :-) using

git tag -l | grep [product_name] | tail -1

I got the latest tag with the product name.

Comment: This also means that my question should be marked as duplicate ... sorry about that.